# Processos longos em C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou precisando fazer uma rotina onde o usuário irá fazer o upload de uma arquivo de carga de dados, e o C# irá processar ele e salvar no banco de dados, sem dar time-out e mostrando o progresso do processo para o usuário.

Minha dúvida é: como fazer?

Não tenho a minima ideia de como fazer ou como procurar no Google. Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Você está querendo processar o arquivo no C# durante o upload? Ou seja, antes do upload terminar, você já quer que o C# esteja processando o arquivo? É isso?

Comment: Não faças isso. Tem tanta coisa que pode correr mal. Podes controlar o timeout do IIS e do ASP.NET mas não podes controlar o timeout do browser. O ASP.ET não foi feito para processamento pesado. Devias colocar logo o ficheiro numa BD ou no disco e ter um serviço externo que o processasse. Para dar informação ao utilizador podias fazer polling ou usar SignalR para notificar.

Comment: Sugestão de busca no Google "Async file upload asp.net mvc". Que vai te levar para o uso de métodos asincronos. Um dos resultados que encontrei em inglês foi https://damienbod.wordpress.com/2013/09/03/mvc-async-file-upload/

Answer (score 1):

No caso de TimeOut você pode fazer a configuração na própria web.config

```
<system.web>
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms timeout="50"/>
</authentication>
<sessionState timeout="60"  />
</system.web>
```

Assim configurando o tempo limite para a Session e Forms.

Answer (score 1):

Não acredito que seja a melhor solução processar um arquivo já no upload. O ideal seria apenas mover o arquivo para uma pasta no seu servidor e ter um serviço que faça o Processamento para você.

Isso evita você travar sua aplicação no ISS e no Banco de Dados fazendo um processamento muito pesado, e tira essa responsabilidade do seu WebSite ou WinForms de fazer o que de fato não seria responsabilidade dele, facilitando manutenção futura em um código que provavelmente é complexo.

Não tem como eu sugerir uma implementação de como salvar o Arquivo já que não sei se você usa MVC, Web Forms ou Win Forms.

Mas no caso do Windows Service você precisa utilizar um objeto do Tipo File System Watcher para monitorar o recebimento de arquivos na pasta do servidor conforme o exemplo:

```
public partial class ProcessadorDeArquivo
{
     protected FileSystemWatcher _fileSystemWatcher { get; set; }

     public ProcessadorDeArquivo()
     {
          _fileSystemWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher(@"C:\Arquivos"); //Pasta que será utilizada para salva os arquivos.
          _fileSystemWatcher.Filter = ".txt" //ExtensãoDoArquivo
          _fileSystemWatcher.Created += FileSystemWatcherCreated;
          _fileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
     }

     /// <summary>
     /// Quando um arquivo é criado na pasta assistida esse evento é disparado
     /// </summary>
     protected void FileSystemWatcherCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
     {
         ProcessarArquivos(e.FullPath); //Método que teria toda a regra de processar.
     }
}
```

**EDIT**   (ASP.NET MVC)

```
//VIEW
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype ="multipart/form-    data" }))
{
<input type="arquivo" name="arquivo" />
<input type="submit" value="salvar" />
}

//CONTROLLER

    public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase arquivo)
{
    // Verify that the user selected a file
    if (arquivo != null) 
    {
        var nome = Path.GetFileName(arquivo.FileName);
        arquivo.SaveAs(@"C:\Arquivos\" + nome);
    }
    return View(); 
}
```

Comment: É ASP.NET MVC. É uma das tags da pergunta.

Comment: Editado com um exemplo simples, não tinha reparado que era MVC.

Comment: Qual seria a melhor forma de fazer a minha aplicação ASP MVC 4, fazer processamento longos sem estourar o time out e mostrar o progresso para o usuário? Exemplo controle financeiro (geração de boletos) que é inicializado pelo usuário.

Comment: Existem formas e formas de mostrar o Progresso, eu não vejo por que tem que ser em tempo real. Por tudo que vi e trabalhei em projeto acho muito melhor "terceirizar" esses processamentos mais custosos. O TimeOut existe por uma razão e se o seu processamento está ultrapassando o valor padrão é por que alguma coisa na Arquitetura está errada. Você pode mostrar o extrato como "Enviado", "Processando" e "Concluido" / "Processamento Falhou" de acordo com uma flag no seu serviço.

Comment: Como eu posso a partir da View chamar um processo destes? Qual seria a melhor forma? Já sei que a inicialização eu faria por ajax, mas internamente teria que montar uma thread? ou o que?

Answer (score 0):

Usando upload em AJAX. Há um um pacote NuGet que configura o jQuery pra isso:

> Install-Package jQuery.AjaxUpload

Exemplo:

```
<script>

    // Variável que guarda seus arquivos
    var files;

    // Eventos que adicionam arquivos à variável de arquivos
    $('input[type=file]').on('change', prepareUpload);

    function prepareUpload(event)
    {
      files = event.target.files;
    }

    $('form').on('submit', uploadFiles);

    function uploadFiles(event)
    {
        event.stopPropagation(); // Parar todos os processamentos
        event.preventDefault();

        // Coloque aqui sua barra de progresso ou seu ícone de loading...

        // Crie um objeto FormData e adicione os arquivos
        var data = new FormData();

        $.each(files, function(key, value)
        {
            data.append(key, value);
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: 'SeuController/Upload',
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            processData: false, // Não processar os arquivos
            contentType: false, 
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
            {
                if(typeof data.error === 'undefined')
                {
                    // Sucesso, envia dados para controller
                    submitForm(event, data);
                }
                else
                {
                    // Erros
                    console.log('ERROS: ' + data.error);
                }
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                // Mais erros
                console.log('ERRORS: ' + textStatus);
                // Desligue seu ícone de loading aqui
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Mas o problema é o processamento, como faço para fazer um processamento pessado sem dar timeout? A carga de arquivo foi um exemplo, porém tenho processos que podem demorar e gerar timeout e não queria que isto acontecesse.

Answer (score 0):

**Configuração**

Você terá de fazer algumas configurações antes de permitir que o usuário faça um upload grande para o seu sistema:

- tamanho limite de upload
- tempo máximo do request

Exemplo de configuração:

```
<system.web> 
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="157286400" executionTimeout="900" /> 
</system.web>

<system.webServer> 
    <security> 
        <requestFiltering> 
                <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="157286400" /> 
             </requestFiltering> 
    </security> 
</system.webServer>
```

**Plugin para fazer upload com progresso**

Eu recomendo um plugin para upload de arquivos que suporta o acompanhamento do progresso do upload: http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Já usei esse plugin em alguns projetos, é realmente muito bom.